# Using Hazel to execute ffmpeg (installed via Homebrew) script to convert video to .gif

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, automation, homebrew

What I want to do is set Hazel to watch a folder for a new video that I create and then when matched, an embedded FFMPEG script converts the video into a gif.

I have the matching criteria done,
[Hazel matching rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9fxj.png)

I have the ffmpeg recipe done,

```
ffmpeg -ss 5.0 -t 2.5 -i $1 -r 15 -filter_complex "[0:v] fps=15, scale=500:-1, split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p]; [b][p] paletteuse" $1.gif
```

But when I put the ffmpeg recipe in the "Embedded Script" dialogue box, I get an error when the match runs.

```
2018-08-09 18:43:15.818 hazelworker[68549] [Error] Shell script failed: Error processing shell script on file /Users/bengregory/Scripts/khgfygfjhbvmnb.mp4.
2018-08-09 18:43:15.818 hazelworker[68549] Shellscript exited with non-successful status code: -900
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant to mention that I've install ffmpeg via homebrew

This is what the embedded shell script looks like
[ffmpeg embedded script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qrdj.png)

I've been trying to get this to work for weeks and so far not found anything that helps. I read through this article on how to use handbrakeCLI, but no luck 
[Hazel and HandbrakeCLI tutorial](http://www.wileywiggins.com/software/2016/11/10/Transcoding-a-movie-library-with-hazel-and-Handbrake-CLI.html)

Any help would be greatly received! Cheers

Comment: Did you try a simpler script, like just running `which ffmpeg` to check that Hazel can actually see ffmpeg? Or running `ffmpeg -v` to see which version it's seeing?

Comment: Also, are you actually running your ffmpeg recipe? Looks like you're running a different command in the embedded script. Maybe I misunderstand how this works.

Comment: There is a typo in your script. Multiple -i options.

Comment: I changed the script to be a simple *say "$1"* which worked

Comment: The different command in the screen shot was me attempting to determine what might be effecting Hazel, so I simplified the command, which I did eventually notice have -i in twice, I amended and no luck

I've tried 
    ffmpeg > /tmp/test.txt 2>&1

which created a text file with the ffmpeg details in